# General error 1651 after a mysql migration

Tags: mysql-5.6

I finished migration from 5.1 to 5.6, and (with the same queries as before) mysql complains right away about:

> General error: 1651 Query cache is disabled; restart the server with
>   query_cache_type=1 to enable it

I don't want the query cache enabled (that's an app with lots of writting), and my file my.ini looks like this:

```
# The MySQL server
[mysqld]
# ... other parameters...

query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_size = 0
```

Also, on connect, my php connection wrapper always executes

```
SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF
```

What I don't understand is

1. Why the parameters apparently do not work
2. Why does mysql even have to complain about a parameter that is disabled when it is the user's choice to do so.

Enlightment needed - Thanks!

Comment: I think the `SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF` is causing this. Have you read (in the [Query Cache Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-configuration.html) page) that: *"If you set query_cache_type at server startup (rather than at runtime with a SET statement), only the numeric values are permitted."*

Comment: And since the server starts with `query_cache_type = 0`, I don't think there is any reason to use that `SET`.

Comment: @ypercube that was it. Please add your comment as an answer and I'll accept it. Changing it to `SET ... = 0` does not change anything, removing totally the setting does. I agree that it is overkill to double specify the parameter on server and client's sessions, but to me it should not behave like this anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the `SET SESSION query_cache_type = OFF` is causing this. In the [Query Cache Configuration](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/query-cache-configuration.html) page it states:

> If you set `query_cache_type` at server startup (rather than at runtime with a `SET` statement), only the numeric values are permitted.

And since you are starting the server with cache disabled, there is no need to use that `SET` anyway.

As to why it throws an error (both with `= OFF` and `= 0`), it may have to do with this note in Server System Variables page:

> - **[query_cache_type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_query_cache_type)**
>
> ...
>
> **If the server is started with `query_cache_type` set to `0`**, it does not acquire the query cache mutex at all, which means that **the query cache cannot be enabled at runtime** and there is reduced overhead in query execution.

My interpretation is that the variable has both Global and Session scope but only if it not set to off at startup.